# Athena can't resolve CSV files from AWS DMS

Tags: amazon-athena, aws-dms

I've DMS configured to continuously replicate data from MySQL RDS to S3. This creates two type of CSV files: a full load and change data capture (CDC). According to my tests, I have the following files:

```
testdb/addresses/LOAD001.csv.gz
testdb/addresses/20180405_205807186_csv.gz
```

After DMS is running properly, I trigger a AWS Glue Crawler to build the Data Catalog for the S3 Bucket that contains the MySQL Replication files, so the Athena users will be able to build queries in our S3 based Data Lake.

Unfortunately the crawlers are not building the correct table schema for the tables stored in S3. 
For the example above It creates two tables for Athena:

```
addresses
20180405_205807186_csv_gz
```

The file **20180405_205807186_csv.gz** contains a one line update, but the crawler is not capable of merging the two informations (taking the first load from **LOAD001.csv.gz** and making the updpate described in **20180405_205807186_csv.gz**).

I also tried to create the table in the Athena console, as described in this blog post:https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/database/using-aws-database-migration-service-and-amazon-athena-to-replicate-and-run-ad-hoc-queries-on-a-sql-server-database/. 
But it does not yield the desired output.

From the blog post:

> When you query data using Amazon Athena (later in this post), you
>   simply point the folder location to Athena, and the query results
>   include existing and new data inserts by combining data from both
>   files.

Am I missing something?

Comment: hello, any news on this? I'm having the same problem here

Answer (score 1):

The AWS Glue crawler is not able to reconcile the different schemas in the initial LOAD csvs and incremental CDC csvs for each table. [This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/loading-ongoing-data-lake-changes-with-aws-dms-and-aws-glue/) blog post from AWS and its associated cloudformation templates demonstrate how to use AWS Glue jobs to process and combine these two type of DMS target outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Athena will combine the files in am S3 if they are the same structure.  The blog speaks to only inserts of new data in the cdc files.  You'll have to build a process to merge the CDC files.  Not what you wanted to hear, I'm sure.

From the [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/database/using-aws-database-migration-service-and-amazon-athena-to-replicate-and-run-ad-hoc-queries-on-a-sql-server-database/):
"When you query data using Amazon Athena (later in this post), due to the way AWS DMS adds a column indicating inserts, deletes and updates to the new file created as part of CDC replication, we will not be able to run the Athena query by combining data from both files (initial load and CDC files)."