# Athena reading from AWS DMS CSV files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-glue, aws-dms

I've configures my DMS to read from a MySQL database and migrate its data to S3 with replication. Everything seems to work fine, it creates big CSV files for all the data and starts to create smaller CSV files with the deltas.

The problem is when I read this CSV files with AWS Glue Crawlers, they don't seem to get these deltas or even worse, they seem to get only the deltas, ignoring the big CSV files.

I know that there is a similar post here: [Athena can't resolve CSV files from AWS DMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49735119/athena-cant-resolve-csv-files-from-aws-dms?answertab=votes#tab-top)

But it is unaswered and I can't comment there, so I'm opening this one.

Does anyone have found the solution to this?

Best regards.

Comment: are you putting the big file and the delta file in the same folder? Is the table definition on the folder level?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same folder. What do you mean with table definition on the folder level?

Comment: By folder level, I meant, create a folder per table and put the full file and the CDC file for the same table in the respective folder for the table. Glue table definition should not be on the individual table. I have written a blog regarding the issue. Please have a read if that help.  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/my-top-5-gotchas-working-aws-glue-tanveer-uddin/

Comment: so yes, I believe our table definition is on folder level. I'll read your blog as soon as I can

Comment: Glue catalog is folder level. Hence you need to make sure file format is same for all files within the folder. After that, run Glue crawler on it to create a table. Next, in Athena run "msck repair table <tablename>". This should let you read all the data in the s3 bucket folder (technically each file is an object in s3, but referring "folder" here for simplicity)